# jquery get previous input text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html in my form:

```
    <div>
    <input type="text" style="margin-top: 10px; float: none;" class="validate[required] span3 m-wrap answopts answerdets" placeholder="Answer Options" id="answeroptions" name="answeroptions[0]">
    <img class="removeanswer" style="width: 50px; margin-top: 9px;" src="../images/remove.png">
</div>
<p class="disoptinputs">
    <input type="radio" style="margin:-85px 0 0 !important;" class="validate[required] coranschk"  id="questionoption" name="questionoption[0][]">
</p>


<div>
    <input type="text" style="margin-top: 10px; float: none;" class="validate[required] span3 m-wrap answopts answerdets0" placeholder="Answer Options" id="answeroptions1" name="answeroptions[0][]">
    <img id="1" class="removeanswer" style="width: 50px; margin-top: 9px;" src="../images/remove.png"></div>
<p class="disoptinputs0">
    <input type="radio" class="coranschk validate[required]" cntr="7" atrid="0" id="questionoption7" name="questionoption[0][]">
</p>

<div>
    <input type="text" style="margin-top: 10px; float: none;" class="validate[required] span3 m-wrap answopts answerdets0" placeholder="Answer Options" id="answeroptions2" name="answeroptions[0][]">
    <img id="2" class="removeanswer" style="width: 50px; margin-top: 9px;" src="../images/remove.png">
</div>
<p class="disoptinputs0">
    <input type="radio" class="coranschk validate[required]" cntr="7" atrid="0" id="questionoption7" name="questionoption[0][]">
</p>
```

This div and p tag is multiple. Now what i want is when user clicks on any radio button i want the value of the input box which is before the radio button inside div. I'd tried this  $(this).prev().prev().val() but it is not working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `$('#answeroptions').val();` may help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.closest()` or `.parent()` to first select the parent of the clicked `radio` before using `.prev()` to locate the `div`. And you do also need to use `.find()` to locate the `input` element.

```
$(this).closest('.disoptinputs').prev().find('input').val();
```

**NOTE**: Since there are multiple input elements you do not need the `id`s as they should be unique.

**UPDATE**

If the `p` elements do not have a common class, this code would not work. In that case then you would have to replace `.disoptinputs` with `p` as in the demo below.

```js
$(function() {
    $('p > :radio').on('change', function() {
        var ival = $(this).closest('p').prev().find('input').val();
        alert( ival );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" style="margin-top: 10px; float: none;" class="validate[required] span3 m-wrap answopts answerdets0" placeholder="Answer Options" id="answeroptions2" name="answeroptions[0][]">
    <img id="2" class="removeanswer" style="width: 50px; margin-top: 9px;" src="../images/remove.png">
</div>
<p class="disoptinputs0">
    <input type="radio" class="coranschk validate[required]" cntr="7" atrid="0" id="questionoption7" name="questionoption[0][]">
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'd tried this and it is not working.

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort PeterKA but i found my answer in ameenulla's answer. So i'd used that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('input').val()
```

Comment: Thanks for such quick reply. I really appreciate it. This code is working fine for all textbox except the input box. If there are 4 div and 4 p tags with radio button then I am not able to get the value of first textbox on first radio button click

Comment: @TaniPartner Don't know why this is happening, it should work with your html.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated you have multiple div and p tag element like that, which results to duplication of id for radio buttons and input. IDs must be unique. you can rather use same class.

And for traversing, You can traverse to closest p tag and then to its previous sibling div and find element in it:

```
$('.disoptinputs :radio').click(function(){
   var previnp = $(this).closest('.disoptinputs').prev().find('input').val();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'd tried this and it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
   var getPrevText = $(this).parent().prev().find("input[type=text]:first").val();
   alert(getPrevText); //returns with the prev Val
});
```

Try the above code, to see it working :)

`$(this)` to target current element. (radio button)

`parent()` to target current element's parent (here it is P tag)

`prev()` to target previous element of P tag (div)

`find("input[type=text]")` to target input tag within prev div

Comment: Thanks ameenulla0007. Thanks very much this is what i want. Thanks very much for your help it make my life